# Kendo Mobile Q3 2013 - Modal view ignoring height and width

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I've upgraded to the latest Kendo UI Mobile (Q3 2013 release) and am noticing that the modal views in my Kendo Mobile application all extend to the height and width of the screen.

Is this by design, or is it a bug that got through? I am very curious because I will need to make some minor adjustments if modal views now extend the height and width of the screen.

Comment: They shouldn't. Can you provide a sample page?

Comment: Okay, no need, I reproduced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a last minute regression. I've just pushed a fix and it will be available through an internal build tomorrow. You can also download the styles from [this sticky post](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/general-discussions/modalview-width-height-set-to-100-regression-in-q3-2013.aspx) in our forums.

Comment: Yikes.. anyway this will be provided as a non-internal build? Our director of programming holds access to our paid Kendo Account, and is unfortunately out at a convention all of this week. I have no way of posting in the premium forums as of now..

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Check the answer for the link.